# how to count how many clock cycles for assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

I need a general explanation about how to count how many clock cycle for an assembly code ?

```
lw  $t1, 0($t8)

li  $t2, -16

div $t1, $t1, $t2

sw  $t1, 0($t8)
```

here I figured that for each instruction will count as one cycle, so the total is 4 cycles for this code. Or 6 cycles if we considered add instruction count as three cycles

Comment: Single-cycle `div` would be nice, but not very realistic

Answer (score 3):

No. Really each instructions takes it's own quantity of clock cycles.
It depends not only on command itself, but on operands of command too.
Real length of each instruction you can find in your processor documentation.
It differs for different processors.